# JRI, Java and R: variable is not accumulated between evals

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

In this code variable `xx` returns 0 instead of 20, shouldn't it be calculated and its value kept between evals?

```
     String[] Rargs = {"--vanilla"};
     Rengine re = new Rengine(Rargs, false, null);

     if (!re.waitForR()) {
         System.out.println("Cannot load R");
         return;
     }

     re.eval("xx = 0");
     for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
         re.eval("xx =  xx + 1");
     }

     int xx = (re.eval("xx")).asInt();
     System.out.println("xx="+xx);
```

This is the result:

```
xx=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer, need to use `asDouble()`:

```
double xx = (re.eval("xx")).asDouble();
```